# How to capture JavaScript event callbacks during run-time?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, browser, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

We are looking for a way to capture all the callback-functions that were executed during runtime

for example, if there function a() runs during page load and function b() run upon click on button 'b' I would like to capture a() run at timestamp1 and then b() at timestamp2 
I need the file/line/column per function (represents where this function starts)

it's good enough if we could solve it using a browser extension/add-on

Comment: Did you consider using the JavaScript profiler that is built into Google Chrome's developer tools?

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that. Maybe intercept the functions by overriding the function prototype and print a line via console.log() but even the chances that will work are slim...but that is a direction

Answer (score 0):

You sure can do this.
Use the nsIEventListenerInfo component.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIEventListenerInfo

Just tell it which element you want to get the listeners for and you get them all. If you want to intercept them and sometimes prevent them then add your own listeners on whatever is being listend to by the target and do event.stopPropagation and e.preventDefault